# The Witcher: Enhanced Edition missing cursor

Tags: the-witcher

I recently purchased The Witcher: Enhanced Edition from Steam. I had played it a few times and everything was fine, but then one time when I started up the game my cursor disappeared on the main menu screen. I tried moving the mouse around everywhere and it didn't work. When I exit the game through the task manager my cursor is back and works fine. Any ideas for what is causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: It does it for me too. I *think* holding shift will bring your cursor back, but it's been a while since I've played. It's just a bug.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks! You can add an answer if you want so that I can accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a minor bug that seems to be fairly common (or so it seemed when I had a similar issue).

Simply hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while you are on the main menu and your cursor will reappear. If you let off of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key at any time, the cursor will disappear and you will be locked in place in the menu.